# Wrap CUDA OpenCV Code to be called from Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

So, I have an accelerated version of an algorithm coded on OpenCV with CUDA support, and I want to call this function and use the result in Python. At the end it returns a `cv::Mat`.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the easiest way to wrap my function?
2. How do I "catch" the resulting `cv::Mat` and convert it to `np.array` to be employed from Python?

I have already considered Cython, SWIG, and the native interface from Python but none of them are clear to me.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code of OpenCV. The the python bindings already contain the relevant code. Also search around, because there are multiple pages and SO questions addressing this topic.

Comment: I have already found several topics but none with CUDA references, actually i'm working based on the code from this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502434/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-calling-a-python-file-from-c-so?rq=1

Comment: So, just in case that works for someone y found easily and fully compatible with OpenCV 3.4.0 and CUDA 9.0 using Boost.  Hope can work for someone, i'm going to upload a working version to github as soon as possible. Thanks a lot for your help